# Why is Vec::with_capacity slower than Vec::new for small final lengths?

Tags: performance, vector, memory-management, rust

Consider this code.

```rust
type Int = i32;
const MAX_NUMBER: Int = 1_000_000;

fn main() {
    let result1 = with_new();
    let result2 = with_capacity();
    assert_eq!(result1, result2)
}

fn with_new() -> Vec<Int> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..MAX_NUMBER {
        result.push(i);
    }
    result
}

fn with_capacity() -> Vec<Int> {
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(MAX_NUMBER as usize);
    for i in 0..MAX_NUMBER {
        result.push(i);
    }
    result
}
```

Both functions produce the same output. One uses `Vec::new`, the other uses `Vec::with_capacity`. For small values of `MAX_NUMBER` (like in the example), `with_capacity` is slower than `new`. Only for larger final vector lengths (e.g. 100 million) the version using `with_capacity` is as fast as using `new`.

**Flamegraph for 1 million elements**
[image: 1 million]

**Flamegraph for 100 million elements**
[image: 100 million]

It is my understanding that `with_capacity` should always be faster if the final length is known, because data on the heap is allocated once which *should* result in a single chunk. In contrast, the version with `new` grows the vector `MAX_NUMBER` times, which results in more allocations.

What am I missing?

### Edit

The first section was compiled with the `debug` profile. If I use the `release` profile with the following settings in `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "vec_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
debug = 2
```

I still get the following result for a length of **10 million**.

[image: 10 million, release profile]

Comment: `Vec`'s capacity grows exponentially, I belive, so for relatively small values, it's expected that it won't allocate *too much*, although it's weird that it's slower, it should always be faster to allocate once.

Comment: Why would a `Vec`, which is ultimately a list and represented as `(pointer, capacity: usize, len: usize)`, grow exponentially?

Comment: When you have a vec with, let's say for exampel, a capacity of 10, and you add an 11th element to it, it needs to allocate a completely new chunk of memory with enough space for at least 11 elements. But it's very inefficient to just re-allocate `current_size + 1` every time. So instead, it'll allocate more, based on some heuristic. I don't know the exact numbers of rust but better than constant realloc would be "whenever vec is full, reallocate for 20% more" or so.

Comment: Whenever a `Vec` is full it doubles its capacity, which yields exponential growth. Exponential growth allows appending to be O(1) amortized -- not *every* append is constant time, but on average they are since the capacity doublings are progressively rarer the larger a vector grows. I'm not sure what point you're making, though, Filipe?

Comment: Do you build in debug or release mode?

Comment: In debug mode, because flamegraph does not produce any graph in release mode.

Comment: Rust's growth factor is 2X. You can see it in [`RawVec::grow_amortized`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs#L393), which is what `Vec` uses internally.

Comment: Adjust your release profile so that it retains all symbols. Not building with optimizations breaks the purpose of benchmarking these primitives.

Comment: Adjusted `Cargo.toml` to build the `release` profile with `opt-level=3` and `debug=2`. Flamegraph was produced with the `flamegraph` crate. I can still reproduce the "issue" with a length of 10 million. `with_capacity` is about 3 x slower than `new`.

Comment: Heap fragmentation, perhaps? Do you have the same result if you swap the order of `with_new` and `with_capacity` in `fn main`?

Comment: trent is likely right. you should test in isolation: run them as 2 separate test runs, not one main() for both.

Comment: Unfortunately testing in debug mode is completely useless for the purpose of benchmarking. Not only are the benchmarks much slower (10-100x), but they are also unrepresentative of the bottlenecks in release builds.

Comment: I'm not quite sure all of the people here claim about debug mode are right, because the overhead of the call to `with_capacity()` is negligible and the other code is the same `push()`. Inlining `push()`, the compiler may be able to eliminate the growth check, but it still should be faster when the vector is big enough even in debug mode since the CPU should predict it. This is probably related more to heap fragmantation lile @trentᶠᵒʳᵐᵉʳˡʸᶜˡ said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce this in a synthetic benchmark:

```
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, BenchmarkId, Criterion};

fn with_new(size: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..size {
        result.push(i);
    }
    result
}

fn with_capacity(size: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(size as usize);
    for i in 0..size {
        result.push(i);
    }
    result
}

pub fn with_new_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("with_new");
    for size in [100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000].iter() {
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::from_parameter(size), size, |b, &size| {
            b.iter(|| with_new(size));
        });
    }
    group.finish();
}

pub fn with_capacity_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("with_capacity");
    for size in [100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000].iter() {
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::from_parameter(size), size, |b, &size| {
            b.iter(|| with_capacity(size));
        });
    }
    group.finish();
}

criterion_group!(benches, with_new_benchmark, with_capacity_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

Here's the output (with outliers and other benchmarking stuff removed):

```
with_new/100            time:   [331.17 ns 331.38 ns 331.61 ns]
with_new/1000           time:   [1.1719 us 1.1731 us 1.1745 us]
with_new/10000          time:   [8.6784 us 8.6840 us 8.6899 us]
with_new/100000         time:   [77.524 us 77.596 us 77.680 us]
with_new/1000000        time:   [1.6966 ms 1.6978 ms 1.6990 ms]
with_new/10000000       time:   [22.063 ms 22.084 ms 22.105 ms]

with_capacity/100       time:   [76.796 ns 76.859 ns 76.926 ns]
with_capacity/1000      time:   [497.90 ns 498.14 ns 498.39 ns]
with_capacity/10000     time:   [5.0058 us 5.0084 us 5.0112 us]
with_capacity/100000    time:   [50.358 us 50.414 us 50.470 us]
with_capacity/1000000   time:   [1.0861 ms 1.0868 ms 1.0876 ms]
with_capacity/10000000  time:   [10.644 ms 10.656 ms 10.668 ms]
```

The `with_capacity` runs were consistently faster than `with_new`. The closest ones being in the 10,000- to 1,000,000-element runs where `with_capacity` still only took ~60% of the time, while others had it taking half the time or less.

It crossed my mind that there could be some strange const-propagation behavior going on, but even with individual functions with hard-coded sizes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3074de6ae654d74ffca396f419652f9b) for brevity), the behavior didn't significantly change:

```
with_new/100            time:   [313.87 ns 314.22 ns 314.56 ns]
with_new/1000           time:   [1.1498 us 1.1505 us 1.1511 us]
with_new/10000          time:   [7.9062 us 7.9095 us 7.9130 us]
with_new/100000         time:   [77.925 us 77.990 us 78.057 us]
with_new/1000000        time:   [1.5675 ms 1.5683 ms 1.5691 ms]
with_new/10000000       time:   [20.956 ms 20.990 ms 21.023 ms]

with_capacity/100       time:   [76.943 ns 76.999 ns 77.064 ns]
with_capacity/1000      time:   [535.00 ns 536.22 ns 537.21 ns]
with_capacity/10000     time:   [5.1122 us 5.1150 us 5.1181 us]
with_capacity/100000    time:   [50.064 us 50.092 us 50.122 us]
with_capacity/1000000   time:   [1.0768 ms 1.0776 ms 1.0784 ms]
with_capacity/10000000  time:   [10.600 ms 10.613 ms 10.628 ms]
```

Your testing code only calls each strategy once, so its conceivable that your testing environment is changed after calling the first one (a potential culprit being heap fragmentation as suggested by @trent_formerly_cl in the comments, though there could be others: cpu boosting/throttling, spatial and/or temporal cache locality, OS behavior, etc.). A benchmarking framework like [`criterion`](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) helps avoid a lot of these problems by iterating each test multiple times (including warmup iterations).

Comment: That's crazy. On my machine it makes no difference: 301.21 ns vs 88.999 ns; 1.8664 us vs 1.7939 us; 5.9134 us vs 19.006 us; 196.08 us vs 193.28 us; 1.9605 ms vs 1.8824 ms; 21.513 ms vs 22.135 ms. Which makes `with_new` slightly faster...

Comment: Nowadays for unknown to me reason there is no difference. I just copy-pasted your benches and runed : https://pastebin.com/sTjuPbge